OpenCV template matching using transparent templates
To make sure I do not xy-problem myself here, I am looking to identify timestamps within a VOD for a video game stream. For example, I would like to programatically capture the timestamps in which we see the GAME overlay for the end of a game here: https://youtu.be/L5dvJXSWf5w?t=671. Similar moments in a match can be seen such at 11:52 where the GO! is on screen.
There are slightly shifting aspects of this element GAME element where it has a white streak in the center that gets smaller over it's duration, but the "outline" is consistent. The naive approach that comes to mind would be to create a sort of template that either only has the outline of GAME, the innards or some sort of combination of the sort. Imgur album of templates: https://imgur.com/a/ssbu-game-templates-sU1kTBn
I've referenced similar posts, such as this one looking to capture the minimap in runescape and templateMatching with a transparent image.
Code I am attempting this with, iterating through all methods and all thresholds from 0.01 to 0.99
Example game images with intentionally varying quality: https://imgur.com/a/QbzU9LA
import cv2
import numpy as np

test_img = cv2.imread(test_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
template_img = cv2.imread(template.template_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
result = cv2.matchTemplate(test_img, template_img, method, none, template_img)
locations = np.where (result <= threshold)
locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))

if 0 < len(locations) < 2000:
    print("method: ", method, "threshold:", threshold, "image:", i, "locations:", len(locations))

I've searched for similar issues, and I'm left wondering if this is somethign to manually calculate the alpha channel akin to this answer or if I am severely misunderstanding how the mask works as a whole, as some answers online implicate that the same template_image should work as the image_mask

The link you provided (at 11 minutes in) doesn't seem to look anything like you describe.  The gameplay does have a countdown timer at the upper right.  Is that what you're looking for?  That's always in the same position.

Sorry about that, I don't think I messed up the formatting on the link, but it should link to 11:11 in the video at the end of the game. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/6zwKpFb

So, what is your goal?  Are you trying to find the countdown time when the game ends?

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't add important information like screenshots in the comments but edit your question. Please use the build-in mechanism for adding screenshots and don't use unnecessary external links. Try to follow the spirit of [ask].
